# Laravel Multi-Tenant (multi-schema) fails with queues

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant

So I've created a large chunk of an api in laravel that is multitenant. There's a jwt issued that comes with a user id and a tenant id. On authenticated requests, I use the tenant in the token to overwrite the postgres schema in the database config. It works fine for all requests, until I get to the queue. I'm realizing now that when I queue a job, event, notification etc it's looking in the public schema (I should have expected that). However, after a full day of digging through code and documentation, I don't see any way to set the schema for a queued job. I have ways of getting around it (pass it as a parameter and set the schema in the constructor) but it's repetitive and also I haven't found a way to do so in a notification (if I'm notifying a user, it'll fail looking up the proper user at _wakeup()). I'm not sure what code I could share to help figure this out, as it's less an implementation problem and more of a "I have no idea how to implement" problem.

I know I could likely create a job that overwrites the schema and THEN synchronously sends the notification but again, I'm falling into very hacky territory.

Comment: "I have no idea how to implement" problems are off-topic for SO.

Comment: @miken32 where would be a better place to ask? I have a good answer now, but for future reference.

Comment: laracasts.com would be your best bet for discussion and big-picture stuff. SO is more geared toward solving specific problems in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented a multi-tenant application and ran into the same problem. Sadly there is no way to hook into a job when it is dispatched.

I created a simple trait to prevent cluttering all jobs with a tenant parameter:

```php
trait TenantAware
{
    protected $tenant;

    public static function dispatchForTenant(Tenant $tenant, ...$args)
    {
        return new PendingDispatch(
            (new static(...$args))->withTenant($tenant)
        );
    }

    public function withTenant(Tenant $tenant)
    {
        $this->tenant = $tenant;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Then you can use [job events](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queues#job-events) to set your schema:

```php
Queue::before(function (JobProcessing $event) {
    // TODO: Retrieve tenant from job payload and set PostgreSQL schema.
});
```

```php
Queue::after(function (JobProcessing $event) {
    // TODO: Reset PostgreSQL schema.
});
```

And dispatch with:

```php
SendInvoiceExampleJob::dispatchForTenant($tenant, $user, invoice);
```

Comment: This is very elegant. Thank you!